# Select sum of same column based on a condition

Tags: sql, sum

I have a SQL table like this:

```
>id|   date   |payed  |amount  
>1 |2015-02-02|1|5  
>2 |2015-02-02|0|2  
>3 |2015-02-02|1|4  
>4 |2015-03-02|1|1
```

The payed column can be ether 0 or 1. How can I return the sum of "amount" for each option of "payed" (0 and 1) based on the date?

```
SELECT (sum of amount for both options of payed) FROM events WHERE date = ?
```

In the example above for date "2015-02-02" I should get 2 and 9.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY all by itself if you'd like, but you can also SUM(CASE) if you want the results as 2 columns of the same row.

```
SELECT date, 
       SUM(case when payed = 1 then amount else 0 end) as PaidAmount,
       SUM(case when payed = 0 then amount else 0 end) as UnPaidAmount
FROM events 
GROUP BY DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   [payed]
  ,[value]
from table
where date = 'target date'
group by payed,value
order by payed desc, value desc
```

this will generate at a result of all transactions on that day, cluster by if they payed then by how much. a quick manual sum and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GROUP BY` statement to group the data according to `payed`, and then apply the condition using `HAVING`.

Code:

```
SELECT payed, SUM(amount) FROM events GROUP BY payed HAVING DATE(date) = '2015-02-02';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should GROUP BY payed to get 2 different results from the 0 and 1 value.

```
CREATE TABLE events
(id int, event_date varchar2(10), payed int, amount int)
;

INSERT ALL 
INTO events (id, event_date, payed, amount)
     VALUES (1, '2015-02-02', 1, 5)
INTO events (id, event_date, payed, amount)
     VALUES (2, '2015-02-02', 0, 2)
INTO events (id, event_date, payed, amount)
     VALUES (3, '2015-02-02', 1, 4)
INTO events (id, event_date, payed, amount)
     VALUES (4, '2015-03-02', 1, 1)
SELECT * FROM dual
;

SELECT event_date
, payed
, SUM(amount)
FROM events 
WHERE event_date = '2015-02-02' 
GROUP BY event_date, payed
;
```

Above code will run on sqlfiddle (set to Oracle 11g) and on my own Oracle 12c database. Syntax might need to be adjusted depending on your DBMS.